# Yup.string.when will always give the result undefined. How can i pass a string value into the .when method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

below my code.

For some reason, the `iscountrycode` is `undefined` when I put it into the .when.
in the `console.log` the result is 'BE'

```js
export function getCheckoutFormSchema(t?: any, iscountryCode?: string) {`
    console.log(iscountryCode)`
    let schema = Yup.object().shape({`
       zip: Yup.string()
            .when(iscountryCode, {
                is: 'BE',
                then: Yup.string()`
```

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: can you please share entire `getCheckoutFormSchema` function code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to apply quotes ('') around `iscountryCode` field.

Try this -

```
let schema = Yup.object().shape({ 
   zip: Yup.string().when('iscountryCode', { is: 'BE', then: Yup.string()...}
)
```

also one more point you need to fact check -

- your schema must have this field you are using 'iscountryCode',

  ```
  let schema = Yup.object().shape({ 
  iscountryCode: Yup.string(),
  zip: Yup.string().when('iscountryCode', { is: 'BE', then: Yup.string()...}
  ```

)

```
both fields should be at the sibling level.
```